# Remote control from Bluetooth Adapter with Firefox OS

Tags: bluetooth, firefox-os

I'm creating an audio player for Firefox OS. I have a bluetooth adapter with play/pause, previous and next buttons.

How can I detect in the app when I press one of buttons?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the bluetooth API is only for certified apps ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions#Internal_%28Certified%29_app_permissions)). There is no way to do this at the moment, at least over bluetooth.